# 2-Dimensional Javascript Array unable to fill with duel for loops

Tags: javascript, for-loop, multidimensional-array, getelementbyid

I am writing a program that needs to use a Javascript 2-dimensional array, so I built this test rig to experiment adding values into the array.

As you can see if you examine the output, the loop runs the inner loop twice and then stops, the outer loop requirement to run `10` times is not enforced.

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<body>
  <input type="button" value="Press me!" id="pressMe" onclick="primaryCommand('textBox')">

  <textarea id="textBox"></textarea>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
function primaryCommand(input){
  arrayTest(input);
}

function arrayTest(input){
  // How large can an array be and still be safe?
  var array = new Array(new Array());
  var obj = document.getElementById(input);
  obj.value="";

  var x = 0, y = 0;

  for (x = 0; x < 10; x++)
  {
    for (y = 0; y < 2; y++)
    {
      array[x][y] = "Hello World, x='" + x + "', y='" + y + "'\n";
      obj.value+=array[x][y];
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Hello World, x='0', y='0'
Hello World, x='0', y='1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your outer array (indexed by `x`) only has one member (a single array). Try this:

```
function arrayTest(input){
  var array = [];
  var obj = document.getElementById(input);
  obj.value="";

  var x = 0, y = 0;

  for (x = 0; x < 10; x++)
  {
    array[x] = [];
    for (y = 0; y < 2; y++)
    {
      array[x][y] = "Hello World, x='" + x + "', y='" + y + "'\n";
      obj.value+=array[x][y];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This works, thank you. Can you explain what is going on? I don't quite understand.

Comment: Does `array[x] = [];` add an array into `x`? I thought that the initialization `var array = new Array(new Array());` would have been enough to put an array into every `x`. It's not clicking. :(

Comment: When you create a 2-dimensional array, you're really creating an *array of arrays*. When you do `var array = new Array(new Array());`, all you're really doing is `var array = [ [] ];`. So you only have one inner array, when you really need one per `x`. So when we do `array[x] = [];`, we create a new inner array *for each `x`*, which is what we want. Does that make sense?

Comment: That is really interesting, so the extra `new Array()` is redundant? Because we add a new array in the outer loop as per your suggestion we no longer need this: `var array = new Array(new Array());` and instead can just have this to initialize: `var array = new Array();`

Comment: I see you removed `var array = new Array(new Array());` in your example. I wonder why this was a suggestion when I was googling how to set this up?

Comment: That's why I changed it to just `var array = [];`. Personally, I prefer array literals to `new Array()` as it is cleaner and similar to the array syntax for many other languages.